# php function pcntl_exec("/bin/sh", "/bin/sh")

Tags: php, shebang, pcntl, execve

According to the [php manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-exec.php#refsect1-function.pcntl-exec-parameters), the function `pcntl_exec` is equal to the syscall `execve`.

So I think

```php
pcntl_exec("/bin/sh", ["/bin/sh"]);
```

should do the same thing like:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
/bin/sh
```

However I got the result: `# /bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: ")" unexpected`

Why?

php version `7.4.3(cli) Zend Engine v3.4.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is incorrect:

> should do the same thing like:
>
> ```
> #!/bin/sh
> /bin/sh
> ```

It is equivalent to running the command `/bin/sh /bin/sh` which will attempt to interpret `/bin/sh` as a shell script.

The actual equivalent of what you want would be:

```
pcntl_exec("/bin/sh", ["-c", "/bin/sh"]);
```